# Cloning object based on content in PHP

Tags: php, object, clone

I seem to be going round in circles here but i have a situation where I when reading some objects i may come across some that contain an array. When this happens i wish to produce new objects based upon the array for example

```
sourceObject(namespace\className)
    protected '_var1' => array('value1', 'value2')
    protected '_var2' => string 'variable 2'
```

Should become

```
childObject1(namespace\className)
    protected '_var1' => string 'value1'
    protected '_var2' => string 'variable2'

childObject2(namespace\className)
    protected '_var1' => string 'value2'
    protected '_var2' => string 'variable2'
```

However due to not quite getting my head around it my clones always end up with the same content (sometimes both are `value1` sometimes `value2`)

Comment: http://php.net/clone always ends up with the same object here. However your properties seem public, so you don't need cloning for what you want to achieve. You can smash it somewhere and process the objects incl. splitting those you'd like to split.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, are you trying to `clone` an object and how that Object is ? `clone` just clones shallow copies.

Comment: nope not code to describing the starting object and the objects i'd be expecting to have at the end.

Comment: @hakre sorry my bad - corrected question as in reality properties are protected

Comment: @GeoffChapman: I've posted an answer that does this via a trait. If you need to do it 100% runtime, you need to use reflection (there is a third move, but that one does not count here). And if it's protected (and not private), you can also extend from that one and then use. So you won't need to edit the original class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method like the following one:

```
trait classSplitClone
{
    public function splitClone($name)
    {

        if (!is_array($this->$name)) {
            return [$this];
        }

        $objs   = [];
        $values = $this->$name;
        $c      = 0;
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $objs[]          = $c ? clone $this : $this;
            $objs[$c]->$name = $value;
            $c++;
        }

        return $objs;
    }
}
```

and then use it in your class(es) as a trait

```
class className
{
    use classSplitClone;

    protected $var1;
    protected $var2;

    function __construct($var1, $var2)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    }
}
```

An example could look like:

```
$obj = new className(['value1', 'value2'], 'variable 2');

print_r($obj->splitClone('var1'));
```

Yielding the following results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => className Object
        (
            [var1:protected] => value1
            [var2:protected] => variable 2
        )

    [1] => className Object
        (
            [var1:protected] => value2
            [var2:protected] => variable 2
        )

)
```

Hope this helps. Alterantively you can access private and protected members also via [**ReflectionObject**](http://php.net/ReflectionObject).

---

The full example code ([Demo](https://eval.in/159885)):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/24110513/367456
 */

/**
 * Class classSplitClone
 */
trait classSplitClone
{
    public function splitClone($name)
    {

        if (!is_array($this->$name)) {
            return [$this];
        }

        $objs   = [];
        $values = $this->$name;
        $c      = 0;
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $objs[]          = $c ? clone $this : $this;
            $objs[$c]->$name = $value;
            $c++;
        }

        return $objs;
    }
}

/**
 * Class className
 */
class className
{
    use classSplitClone;

    protected $var1;
    protected $var2;

    function __construct($var1, $var2)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
    }
}

/*
 * Example
 */
$obj = new className(['value1', 'value2'], 'variable 2');

print_r($obj->splitClone('var1'));
```

Comment: Thank you much appreciated the trait did the job but then to use reflection was inspired idea that had slipped me by so will try to implement that.

Comment: @GeoffChapman: If you're looking for reflection, then this is what you can exploit for access: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php